# Ruby Net/Http how to get body of page with status code 3xx

Tags: ruby, request, net-http

I use net/http ruby's library to get the html response, but i can't get the body of the page with the status code 3xx

Page Body:

```
<div class="flash-container">
    <div class="flash flash-success">
        Il tuo indirizzo email è stato modificato con successo.
        <a href="#" onclick="removeFlash(this);" class="close">×</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Request:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data({
      'email' => email,
      'email-confirm' => email_confirm,
      'password' => password
})
request['Cookie'] = 'ACCOUNT_SESSID=' + token
response = http.request(request)
```

Response:

```
response.code  # '302'
response.body # ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to follow the redirect (`302` code). The [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) have a great example for doing this.

I've included this below, along with a check to return the body if it exists. If you never want to follow the redirect, you could change the `else` condition to return `response.code`, and empty string, false, or whatever's appropriate. Here's the full example:

```
def fetch(uri_str, limit = 10)
  raise ArgumentError, 'too many HTTP redirects' if limit == 0

  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(uri_str))

  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess then
    response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection then
    if response.body_permitted?
      response
    else
      location = response['location']
      warn "redirected to #{location}"
      fetch(location, limit - 1)
    end
  else
    response.value
  end
end
```

The code is pretty straight forward, calling itself recursively if the code from `Net::HTTP.get_response` returns a redirect, pointing to the new location.

You can follow up to ten redirects with this approach, which should be ample, though should likely adjust to suit or circumstances.

Then, when you run `fetch(your_url)`, it should follow the redirect until it lands on a page and can return the body. I.E.

```
res = fetch(your_url)
res.body
```

Let me know how you get on with this, or if you've any questions!

Comment: thank you, but I need to get the body of the page with status code 3xx, not the redirected page, but in the `response.body` return a empty string, while in python returns me the the response code

Comment: Thanks @MattVoid - I've updated my answer to reflect this. The [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html#method-c-body_permitted-3F) show a `body_permitted?` method which checks the [`HAS_BODY`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPRedirection.html) constant. You can then return this if it exists, or handle in a custom manner if it doesn't (in my example, by following the redirect, though this could easily be adapted to return a custom response). Hope that helps!

Comment: Did this help at all @MattVoid?